# How to set layout on 7" two different tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resolution

I have two 7 inch tablet one tablet (800*480) and second tablet (1024*600). I have facing problem following :-

**1.  Both can run on layout-mdpi and layout-large so how can i make different folder for run my app both resolution.**

Application run xml for mdpi layout in both tablet:-

```
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
```

Application run xml for large layout in both tablet:-

```
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

I can implement http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html this but not use full to me.

or

try so many link but still same problem both tablet running in same layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this.It worked for me

```
layout-sw600dp
```

Comment: try this ..layout-hdpi for 800*480 (I guess u already used that)

Comment: thanks its working  layout-sw600dp for (1024*600) and layout-mdpi for 800*480

Answer (score 4):

7" tablets—Android 3.2 introduces a new way to specify resources for more discrete screen sizes. The new technique is based on the amount of space your layout needs (such as **600dp of width**), rather than trying to make your layout fit the generalized size groups (such as large or xlarge).

```
res/layout-sw600dp/
res/layout-sw600dp-land
res/layout-sw600dp-port
```

- 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800
  hdpi, etc).
- 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
- 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

UI to differentiate between sizes such as 7” and 10” tablets

1. **res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)**
2. **res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)**
3. **res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)**

***xlarge is a configuration qualifier for extra large screens.**** When you append this string to a resource directory name (such as layout-xlarge), it indicates to the system that these resources are to be used on devices that have an extra large screen.

Answer (score 1):

> I have two 7 inch tablet one tablet (800*480) and second tablet
>   (1024*600). I have facing problem following :-

I have faced the Same issue. as a workaround i have make the xml file for (800*480) in same layout folder as Default.

Also used layout-sw320dp  for the Devices like GalaxyNexus
and for 7'' Tablet i have make layout-sw600dp for 7'' Screen Tablet
and for 10'' Tablet i have make layout-sw700dp for 10'' Screen Tablet

For Example : you have the xml file named "activity_main.xml"

> 1) inside `layout` folder--> put activity_main.xml with layout according
>   to nexus one(480*800 hdpi)
>
> 2) inside `layout-sw320dp` folder--> put activity_main_tab.xml with
>   Layout according to Galaxy Nexus(720*1280 xhdpi) Device which
>   should take the layout from `layout-600dp` but will take layout from
>   `layout-320dp`
>
> 3) inside `layout-600dp` folder--> put activity_main_tab.xml with layout according
>   to tablet 7'' Screen
>
> 4) inside `layout-700dp` folder--> put activity_main_tab.xml with layout according
>   to tablet 10'' Screen

after making the Layout formated as above. i have checked runtime width and height of device. and set the layout file accordingly.

```
if (displayWidth >= 552 && displayHeight >= 976 || displayWidth >= 976
                && displayHeight >= 552) { 
   Log.i(TAG, "in tab xml");            
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tab); 
}else{ 
Log.i(TAG, "in Simple xml");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}
```

Hope this will Help.