# Android: Text in TextView not aligned well

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` in `RelativeLayout` in which I am setting the text from a string and that string contains the text more than 2 lines. But I want to set the Text into two lines. All is working but the problem is the Text in two lines is not aligned well.

Here is how it looks:

**This is the text of first line
which contains a dummy text**

As you can see I have set left margin of 5 then it only applied on first line but not on the second one. So what is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
</TextView>
```

Comment: But your text is in one line, edit your question to show how exactly you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890153/how-to-know-which-phone-support-which-layouthdpi-mdpi-and-xhpi

Comment: In your string.xml file you have to include "\n" wherever you want so the after that the next text will display in next line.

Comment: post a screen shot. also set textsize for your textview. Also remove android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" because your textview is in relative layout and LeftOf="@+id/image".