# Run my application on different devices with different resolution

Tags: android, xml, layout, landscape, absolutelayout

i'm creating a app in Android using eclipse, but i don't have idea with create layouts for more of one resolution of screen.
My app is in Absolute Layout in a screen landscape of 1024x600, but if i execute this app in other resolution, the layout is crashed, all buttons and others components is out of the position.
The device who i use is a tablet with 7". I need to adapt the app for tablets of 10" and others...
i tried relative layout but i don't know how to use this layout to organize the components.
somebody can help me to try find a answer.

Comment: You will want to read through the Android documentation on supporting multiple screens, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. Also, AbsoluteLayout has been deprecated since API 3 and is not suggested for use.

Comment: you recommend relativelayout?

Comment: Personally, yes. I prefer RelativeLayout and use LinearLayout only when necessary. It is just a matter of what works best and makes the most sense in your situation. Are items all over the screen or are they sequentially horizontal/vertical?

Comment: all over the screen, is a restaurant menu, is the reason for i use absolutelayout, more easily to align the components where i need

Comment: I would use RelativeLayout so that it will dynamically position and size the items based on the screen size.

Comment: In the absolutelayout i can set the componente exactly where i need, using android:layout in  pixel, how to use relative layout to set location?

Comment: The first item of a RelativeLayout is positioned to the upper left corner of the screen. From there you state new items' positions based on position to that first item, or other items as they are added to the layout. Check the documentation, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html & http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html Its helps you. you have make a separate design for mobile and tablet, also the drawable images.

Answer (score 0):

Read android devices support multiple screen doc http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and also read supporting different screen sizes doc http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html.

See below link for more info about phone supporting device:-

[how to know which phone support which layout(hdpi , mdpi and xhpi)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890153/how-to-know-which-phone-support-which-layouthdpi-mdpi-and-xhpi)