# Android Emulator showing hdpi for 720 X 1280

Tags: android, drawable, android-virtual-device, screen-resolution, hdpi

I am trying to emulate Samsung J7 on my Android Emulator.
I selected Create Virtual Device -> New Hardware Profile -> Entered J7 configuration (Size 5.5 inches & Resolution 720 X 1280 ) 
 I also created Samsung Galaxy Nexus xhdpi AVD from default option 
Problem is that for My custom device it is showing hdpi and for default it is showing xhdpi.
(Screenshot is attached, I need this answer for my drawable related issues) 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18158827/7676750

Comment: @Sallu thanks. I've already seen this. My requirement in layman terms is that I want different UI as per hdpi / xhdpi